# How to deploy complex Ethereum app split into multiple contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, dapp-development

If you develop a complex dApp and have to split it into separate individual contracts because of the deployment gas limit, What's a clean process/pattern for deploying and linking the individual contracts together?

Comment: What i do is to create one contract as "relay" to others. There you keep all addresses to other contracts and when you deploy new/changed contract you just change address of it in relay. Then from there you call functions to related contracts to set new address.

Comment: Deploy them one by one. If contract X requires the address of contract Y at construction, then deploy contract Y first, and use its address when deploying contract X.

Comment: The problem of that is that it makes it more difficult/cumbersome for others to verify that a certain source-code matches a particular dApp. Also, how would one nicely automate this process? Truffle Migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is how i do it.

`Relay.sol`:

```
contract Relay {

    IOtherContract private otherContractInterface;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner, "Sender is not owner");
      _;
    }

    function initialize(address _otherContractAddress) external onlyOwner {

        otherContractInterface = IOtherContract(_otherContractAddress);
    }
}
```

`OtherContract.sol`:

```
contract OtherContract {


  address relay;

  modifier onlyRelay() {
      require(msg.sender == relay, "Sender is not relay.");
      _;
  }

  function setRelay(address _relay) external onlyOwner {
      relay = _relay;
  }
}
```

And then you call `OtherContract.setRelay(relayAddress)` from your owner account or wrap it in `initialize` function and call `setRelay` right after newContract address is set.
**EDIT**: also use interfaces/abstract classes when accessing contract from other contract, it will save you gas and allow more code to be put into single contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you import one contract into another, the bytecode is just attached at the end. This leads to very big files/bytecodes if you import multiple contracts. What I do is to implement an interface for each contract and then just import this. Then I hardcode the address of the corresponding contracts into the contract that implements them. This ensures there is no way to tamper with the design.

e.g.: (pseudocode)

```
mycontract1.sol
implements Imycontract2.sol
{

  Imycontract(address).callFunction()
}
```

where Imycontract2.sol is just a dummy with empty implementations of the functions of mycontract2.sol